# \newcommand / \newenvironment - optional parameters

Tags: latex

I'm experimenting with my own commands and environments and now I'm facing those problems:

1. How to create command `\foo{parameter}[optional]` or environment called `\begin{bar}{parameter}[optional]`?
2. How to create command `\foo[optional_1]...[optional_n]{parameter}`

I've tried

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3][][]{#1#2#3}    - failed
\newcommand{\foo}[3][2][][]{#1#2#3} - failed
```

Does anyone know some hint? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using the xparse package (part of the LaTeX3 development efforts):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{O{}O{}m}{%
  % Code with optional #1 and #2 with empty defaults
}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mO{}}{%
  % Code with optional #2 with empty default
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{O{}}{%
% Start code with optional #1
}{%
%  End code with optional #1
}
```

Optional arguments are a bit different in xparse to with \newcommand. You can detect whether one is given or not:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {Code without #2}
   {Code with #2}%
}
```

You'll see that this works by using a lower case 'o', whereas the upper case 'O' then requires a default value (which I've made empty by including an empty group).

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply, I did't have time to try it.

Thanks a lot for sloving my problem with multiple parameters

Answer (score 22):

1. You can't create a `\foo{parameter}[optional]` command simply; you can, however, create a `\foo[optional]{parameter}` command with

   ```
   \newcommand{\foo}[2][default]{Mandatory: #2; optional: #1}
   ```

   If you call it as `\foo{given}`, it will produce `Mandatory: given, optional: default`; if you call it as `\foo[bonus]{given}`, it will produce `Mandatory: given, optional: bonus`.  This is probably how you should do it—that will look better with the rest of your LaTeX code.  Creating a new environment with optional parameters is done similarly with

   ```
   \newenvironment{env}[2][def]{(#1,#2)\begingroup}{\endgroup}
   ```

   where `#1` is again the optional argument; this is again written as `\begin{env}[opt]{req}...\end{env}`.  If you *really* want a command in the other form, see the end of my answer.
2. The TeX FAQ has an answer about writing commands with [more than one optional argument](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=twooptarg).  There are two options to how to do it.  The underlying idea is to define a command which takes an optional argument, and then runs another command which itself takes an optional argument, etc.; the *twoopt* package encapsulates this.

---

If you *really* want a command like `\reversed{mandatory}[optional]`, you can do it like so.  First, you define a command which takes a required argument, stores it in a macro, and then forward it onto another command.  This second command takes an optional argument, and uses the defined command and the optional argument.  Putting this all together, we get

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reversed}[1]{\def\reversed@required{#1}\reversed@opt}
\newcommand{\reversed@opt}[1][def]{Required: \reversed@required; optional: #1}
\makeatother
```

You can then use `\reversed{mandatory}[optional]` or just `\reversed{mandatory}`, and everything should work.

Comment: +1 nice summary. A particular issue is if the macro is used incorrectly, with the optional arg being ommitted: "\reversed[optarg]". The error messages will have poor readability with your code: it's worth testing for \reversed@opt being equal to "[" and flagging this as a fatal error if it is.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure what I think about checking for `[`—you're right that it will behave unexpectedly, but it actually has a perfectly well-defined behavior (printing `Required: [; optional: def`, and then typesetting `optarg]`).  The *actual* advice I would give is "don't use this technique"—while it's technically possible, it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time spent on this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Consider also the xargs package.  The following is an example from its documentation.

Set it up in the usual way,

```
\usepackage{xargs}
```

and then if you define

```
\newcommandx*\coord[3][1=1, 3=n]{(#2_{#1},\ldots,#2_{#3})}
```

(which means to use "1" for the first argument, if it is not specified, and to use "n" for the third).  Then

```
$\coord{x}$
```

yields (sans subscripts)

(x1, . . . , xn)

and

```
$\coord[0]{y}$
```

yields (again, sans subscripts, and y replaces the mandatory parameter)

(y0, ..., yn)

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already comprehensive answers, but is some cases, I want to give different definitions for different situations. There is a still very basic yet simple solution for this. I write it down in case any other need it.

```
% ----------------------------------
%! TEX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% Author:       Troy_Daniel 
% Email:        Troy_Daniel@163.com
% ----------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Caption}[3]{%
    \textcolor[rgb]{0.36, 0.72, 0.80}{\Large #1}
    {\def\tmp{#3}
    \ifx\tmp\empty                                  % the third parameter is not provieded
        \textcolor[rgb]{0.96, 0.66, 0.35}{\small#2}
    \else                                           % non-empty third parameter
        \textcolor[rgb]{0.96, 0.66, 0.35}{\small[#3]#2}
    \fi}}
\begin{document}

\Caption{First}{Second}{}

\Caption{First}{Second}{Third}

\end{document}
```

And the result is shown below, different definitions for optional parameter(s):
[image: Different definitions for optional parameter(s)]

Comment: This doesn't make the third argument optional, since you have to supply an empty `{}`. Optional means "don't supply anything" usually.

Answer (score -1):

Troy Daniel's solution worked perfectly for me. This custom 'example' environment allows to name your examples or not using an optional parameter.

```
\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{examplex}[1][]{
\def\optpar{#1}
\refstepcounter{examplex}\par\medskip\noindent\textbf{
    Example~\thesection.\theexample
    \ifx\optpar\empty
    {.}
    \else
    { - }#1.
    \fi
    } 
    \rmfamily
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2em}{0em}}{
    \medskip
    \end{adjustwidth}
}
```